# Angular iframe does not load url quickly with DomSanitizer

Tags: angular

I have an iframe within my application. Since the iframe url is from another domain, I use DomSanitizer. All works well but when I run my application, for a second I see 'WebPage not found' (see image) in the iframe. To narrow down the problem, if I remove DomSanitizer the problem disappears. How can I fix this when using DomSanitizer? I have tried using a pipe but the problem remains the same.

[image]

```
getUrl() {
    return this.sanitizer.bypassSecurityTrustResourceUrl( this.url );
}
```

HTML

```
<iframe [src]="getUrl()" style="width: inherit"
      [height]="frameHeight"
      frameborder="0" allowfullscreen="allowfullscreen">
</iframe>
```

Comment: What does your getUrl function look like? Also, don’t use a function call for this in the first place..

Answer (score 0):

I solved the problem by having a setter in the url input property and setting the this.sanitizer.bypassSecurityTrustResourceUrl in there as below

```
_url: string;
get url(): string {
    return this._url;
}

@Input() set url( value: string ) {
    this._url = value;
    if( this._url ) {
        this.urlSafe = this.sanitizer.bypassSecurityTrustResourceUrl( this._url );
    }
}
```

I then use urlSafe in HTML